# Responsive problem more desktop columns with content to one ordered column

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, multiple-columns

I am trying resolve this responsive problem. Point is, have in mobile version right order divs with numbers #1 - #7

Pic. 1: Desktop. Divs (with #number) are country list ordered by priority. In div.column may be ANY divs with #number (first column has 1, second 2...)

[image]

Pic. 2: Moblie version. Columns are one below the other BUT divs with #number has wrong order.

[image]

Is possilbe somehow solve this problem?

My solutions are all bad.

1. Have 2 div.wrapper with all contents, one for mobile second for desktop and show/hide right wrapper on right screen width. - BAD (there are many other javascript scripts with reading this columns and so on...)
2. After page load (doc ready) rearrange items with js script. - BAD the same problem as in case 1
3. Cancel div.column element but this will be work only in case the same nubmer of div with #number... if in first div.column will be 1 div #1 and in second div.column few div with #nuber it will collapse.

Somebody some hints?

Comment: In my opinion you should use grid(grid template areas) instead of flex that will give you more control

Comment: It would be helpful if you post the code